# Full-window view in front of a collection view

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I'm trying to implement the following behavior:

- Long press on a collection view brings a full-window view (call it LetterView) to the front
- Subsequent gestures/touches are only processed by the LetterView.

(edit: I should mention that I want a transparency effect of seeing the collectionview items beneath LetterView)

I seem to be running into behavior that everyone else is trying to implement, though - my touches get processed by both the LetterView and the collection view. I.e. I can scroll the collection view AND have hits processed by my topmost view.  Showing the view hierarchy in XCode clearly shows LetterView at the front, and both the UICollectionView and the LetterView are subviews of UICollectionWrapperView.

LetterView is a UIView subclass with a UIViewController subclass. It's added to the view hierarchy programmatically, inside my UICollectionViewController subclasses's `viewDidLoad` method, like so:

```
super.viewDidLoad()
letterDrawingViewController = LetterDrawingViewController()
let viewFrame : CGRect = self.collectionView!.frame
letterDrawingViewController.view = LetterDrawingView.init(frame:viewFrame)
letterDrawingView = letterDrawingViewController.view
self.addChildViewController(letterDrawingViewController)
letterDrawingViewController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
collectionView?.addSubview(letterDrawingView)
```

- It doesn't appear to be a first responder issue, as I tried overriding canBecomeFirstResponder in LetterView and assigning it first responder status when I move it to the front
- I tried setting userInteractionEnabled=FALSE on the CollectionView, but keeping it true on the LetterView after I moved LetterView to the front. This disabled all touch events for both views
- I tried setting exclusiveTouch=True for LetterView when I moved it to the front.  This didn't appear to do anything.

Aside from any specific tips, are there any general techniques for debugging hit-testing like this? According to the docs on hit-testing in iOS, iOS should prefer the "deepest" subview that returns yes for `hitTest:withEvent:`, which, since LetterView is a subview of collectionview, and in front of all it's cells, should be the front? Is there any logging I can enable to see a hit test over the view hierarchy in action?

Thank you!

Nate.

Comment: If letterView is full screen, you probably don't want to add it as a subview of the collection view like you are. Maybe try adding it to the application's window instead and see how that does. At least in that instance it should intercept all the touch events.

Comment: I am adding it to the UICollectionViewWrapperView, instead, and it seems to be pretty close. Now I can disable userinteraction on the CollectionView, and enable it on letterView.  Feel free to make this an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: Sure, I'll post it. Thanks! One tiny side note - be careful about dissecting apple's views like that. There's a good chance, especially if you are supporting multiple versions of iOS that the hierarchy might change and break stuff in ways you wouldn't expect. I learned my lesson the hard way messing with subViews of UIImagePicker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If letterView is full screen, you probably don't want to add it as a subview of the collection view like you are. Maybe try adding it to the application's window instead and see how that does. At least in that instance it should intercept all the touch events.

Another method, although admittedly a more fragile feeling one, would be to enable and disable user interaction on the collectionView as you present and dismiss letterView.
So, when letterView is about to be presented, you can call

```
    self.collectionView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

and if you also know when that view is about to be dismissed you can call

```
    self.collectionView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

The only thing here to worry about is that you don't get into a bad state where your letterView is not presenting and your collectionView is also ignoring a user's touch. That will feel totally broken.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst I think you can deal with your issue somewhat easily I think you are making a design mistake. It feels like you are trying to code this thinking like a web developper by adding a child view to your view and trying to intercept the touches there like one would do in a modern JavaScript single page app. In iOS I think this is bad design. You should segue or present the new viewController using the methods provided by apple.

So your code should look soothing like:

```
letterDrawingViewController = LetterDrawingViewController()
self.presentViewController(letterDrawingViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

iOS8 has the added benefit of allowing you to have awesome custom transitions. Take a look at this : http://www.appcoda.com/custom-segue-animations/

Comment: Thanks, but I want a transparency effect of the collectionview beneath LetterView. using presentviewcontroller, or pushing the new view onto the nav controller stack doesn't quite give me the behavior that I would like.

Comment: You just need to set the presented view controller background to transparent.  You acheive any effect by presenting a view controller as you can by adding a subview. The touch event problem is only the first in a series of bugs and issues you'll uncover overtime as you add features. The view hierarchy is different between versions of iOS.